# flynax giving mysql error while updating common configuration

Tags: php, jquery, plugins, smarty

Hi. I've been confused by this the last two days.

I am using Flynax for my Smarty project, but inside I can't update the admin app->common->configuration

I am getting this error:

```
MYSQL ERROR

    Error:  Unknown column 'Array' in 'having clause'
    Query:  SELECT `IP` AS `Count` FROM `fl_login_attempts` WHERE `IP` = '123.236.230.132' AND `Status` = 'fail' AND `Interface` = 'admin' GROUP BY `Date` HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `Date`, NOW()) < Array
    Function:   error
    Class:  rlDb
    File:   /home/autotrad/public_html/includes/classes/rlDb.class.php (line# 116)
```

Does anyone know how to solve it - is anyone getting the same error?

Comment: check your query generating code... you are passing array as param.. add your relavant php code

Comment: hello @Sundar this queries are inbult of flynax i think the problem is in register_globals in php.ini right now it is on how can i make it off through php coding?

Comment: use ini_set function to switch off the register_ global. But HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, Date, NOW()) < Array  your comparison value just echo and check it.

Comment: yup got it thank you yaar..

Answer (score -2):

Yea Sundar disabling "register_globals" will solve the problem for sure!